# How to have full screen and hide toolbar/statusbar in Qt Quick app for Meego Device?

Tags: qt, toolbar, nokia, qml, meego

I am new to Meego development and my Qt Quick Application for Meego Device require to have full screen and not toolbar and no status bar. Also only for Portrait screen orientation.

I am using Pagestack for application navigation from one page to other. I got to be successful in locking to Portrait usiong Pagestack properties. But for toolbar and status bar no success. It has properties like

```
showStatusBar: false
    showToolBar: false
```

**But these are read only and could not help me to hide toolbar and status bar.**

**I just want to know how to make application using fullscreen or either way how to hide status bar and toolbar?**

Even using following code in qmlapplicationviewer.cpp

```
void QmlApplicationViewer::showExpanded()
{
#ifdef Q_OS_SYMBIAN
    showFullScreen();
#elif defined(Q_WS_MAEMO_5)
    showMaximized();
#else
    show();
#endif
}
```

so showMaximized() method to access not helping out yet.
I tried using this method in main.cpp file also like this

```
QWidget window;
    window.showMaximized ();
```

But no results so for.

Any ideas would be highly appriciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the toolbar via QML and the components. [This](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/How_to_Remove_Toolbar_from_MeeGo_Harmattan_Application) article should help on how.

Comment: Thanks, it solves the issue by just assigning null to tools. But very bad solution may be.

Answer (score 2):

Try [QWidget::showFullScreen()](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#showFullScreen).

Answer (score 0):

In the file: qmlapplicationviewer.cpp

change:

```
void QmlApplicationViewer::showExpanded()
{
#if defined(MEEGO_EDITION_HARMATTAN) || defined(Q_WS_SIMULATOR)
    showFullScreen();
#elif defined(Q_WS_MAEMO_5) || defined(Q_OS_QNX)
    showMaximized();
#else
    show();
#endif
}
```

to:

```
void QmlApplicationViewer::showExpanded()
{
#if defined(MEEGO_EDITION_HARMATTAN) || defined(Q_WS_SIMULATOR)
    showFullScreen();
#elif defined(Q_WS_MAEMO_5) || defined(Q_OS_QNX)
    //showMaximized();
    showFullScreen();
#else
    //show();
    showFullScreen();
#endif
}
```

Works great for me. Cheers.